# How to grep the output of grep?

Tags: arrays, bash

After using bash -x to debug this script, it appears that a problem occurs near $InvalidText, where grep treats the output of InvalidText as separate file names.
The only solution I can think of is to direct the output of InvalidText to a file, then grep that file.. are there any other alternatives?

```
# find IP address of Invalid user and give the fake name they tried. Loop for all IP addresses
        InvalidText=$(grep "Invalid user" syslog.log)
        IPInvalidUser=$(grep "Invalid user" syslog.log | awk '{print $NF}' | uniq)
        InvalidUserarray=( $IPInvalidUser )
                for FAKEHOST in "${InvalidUserarray[@]}"
                do
                        fakeinfo=$(grep ${FAKEHOST} $InvalidText | cut -d: -f5 | awk '{print $3}')  
                        echo -e "Invalid user attempts:\n"      
                        echo -e "$FAKEHOST      $fakeinfo"
                done
```

Comment: You can grep the output of anything, including grep, by piping to grep: `grep "Invalid user" syslog.log | grep "some text"`. You can grep in a variable using a here string: `grep "some text" <<< "$InvalidText"`

Comment: What file are you trying to `grep` in with `grep ${FAKEHOST} $InvalidText`?  It seems you have two strings there with no source of data to search within.

Comment: $InvalidText returns some data from the syslog file. I am searching for FAKEHOST (some IP address) in $InvalidText. Yep @JohnZwinck that's why I was thinking of putting $InvalidText into a file first or something.

Comment: @thatotherguy the here string worked great! Cheers.

Comment: The indentation in vim is a bit strange though.. the first << are one colour and the last < another colour

Comment: *syntax highlighting

Comment: `grep ${FAKEHOST} $InvalidText` says' search for the first word in `${FAKEHOST}` in files named after every other word in `${FAKESHOST}` and files named after every word in `$InvalidText`. grep doesn't accept the data to search *in* on the command line like that.

Comment: If you post the contents of `InvalidText` and  what should be contained in `fakeinfo`, certainly answers will be coming ?

Comment: Change this "grep ${FAKEHOST} $InvalidText " with "echo $InvalidText | grep ${FAKEHOST}  " and see if it works.. for the cut command. The former case wont work as you get some data in $InvalidText variable rather than getting just a single file name.